# How Can speed up Neo4j Importing CSV FILE

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm using the code below to import the data, but it takes a very long time, knowing that the size of the data is not large only (3.3 megabytes). Is it possible to modify the code or use another method to speed up the data import process?

code:
`LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///Musae-Github.csv' as line`
`WITH toInteger(line.source) AS Source, toInteger(line.destination) AS Destination` 
`MERGE (a:person {name:Source})`
`MERGE (b:person {name:Destination})`
`MERGE (a)-[:Freind ]-(b)`
`RETURN *`

Answer (score 1):

You can use transaction batching to speed up importing csv files to Neo4j.  Also, ensure that you have index on person.name

```
CREATE INDEX PersonNameIndex IF NOT EXISTS FOR (p:Person) ON (p.name)
```

Below is the updated script:

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
CALL apoc.load.csv('file:///Musae-Github.csv') yield map as line return line
','
WITH toInteger(line.source) AS Source, toInteger(line.destination) AS Destination  MERGE (a:Person {name:Source}) MERGE (b:Person {name:Destination}) MERGE (a)-[:Friend ]-(b)
', {batchSize:10000, iterateList:true, parallel:true});
```

reference: https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/4.3/import/load-csv/#_transaction_batching

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks great, although I don't know if you need to RETURN * at the end.

Try seeing how long it takes just to process the file:

```
LOAD CSV FROM "yourpathhere" as line
return linenumber(), datetime(), line
```

This should be very fast.